# Where does Rundeck store job logs?

Tags: rundeck

Let's say I connect to the Rundeck UI at `<server>:4440`.  I construct a job, schedule it to run every 15 min., then wait a few days.  Then, I want to do some analysis of the Job runlogs, gathering some statistics from logging statements I added.  The problem is...  **where are the logs?**  Are they somewhere on `<server>`?  Or on some other node (if so, what server and what file path).

I know I can download the logs, but they're big, so I'd rather do the statistics gathering close to where the log data live.

Answer (score 2):

The execution logs outputs are stored in the location specified in your framework.properties file. By default:

framework.logs.dir=$RDECK_BASE/var/logs

"Directory for log files written by core services and Rundeck Server’s Job executions"

ref. [Configuration File reference](https://rundeck.org/docs/administration/configuration/configuration-file-reference.html#framework.properties).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Doesn't matter.   The only directory that contains the string "var/log" is /var/logs, and that doesn't seem to have the very large logfiles I'm looking for.